# Compress Individual Files using YUI Compressor .Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, yui-compressor

How can i compress individual css files using YUI build task (or otherwise).
Scenario:
I have

- **Style.css,**
- **IFrame.css,**
- **Grid.css**

I can compress and merge these files to **main.min.css** (no problem here, got a sample from yui on codeplex).

However, I also have a **Contact.css** that is only used on the contact page. How do I compress this file seperately from the others? i.e into **contact.min.css**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using [Cassette](http://getcassette.com). The next VS will have this built in.

Answer (score 1):

Might look into [RequestReduce](http://requestreduce.com/). 
We are also creating a bundling/minification for ASP.NET (MVC, Web Pages, Web Forms). See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue right, you can create multiple bundles.Here I'm using YUI Compressor.Net , but it can be standard bundle from System.Web.Optimization namespace.

```
        var cssBundleConfig = new CssCompressorConfig();
        var cssTransform = new YuiCompressorTransform(cssBundleConfig);

        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Content/basecss", cssTransform).Include(
                  "~/Content/Css/Style.css",
                  "~/Content/Css/IFrame.css",
                  "~/Content/Css/Grid.css"
                  ));
        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Content/contactcss", cssTransform).Include("~/Content/Css/Contact.css"));
```

And call render on UI like:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/basecss")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/contactcss")
```

But this is runtime process, not build phase task. May be there is similair solution for build.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following plug-in http://chirpy.codeplex.com/. It allows you to compress all your css and javascript at build time automatically. I've used it in a few projects and seems to work well.